# Human power plant

Tags: energy, far-future

Imagine if we could build a power plant made of humans just like in *The Matrix* movie.

I don't know what is the best way to harvest energy from humans short of using them as a fuel (which I want to avoid to make it sustainable). I would guess it's either forcing them to pedal dynamos to turn mechanical power into electricity or using them to warm up some sort of thermal carrying fluid.

Let's also be realistic and apply efficiency factor of energy harvesting. If we were able to use entire Earth population to generate energy, what is the maximum city size (you can also read this as a population) we can fully supply with purely human generated power?

Comment: I direct you to [this wonderful answer](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/57712/21704)

Comment: @Anketam Boy, whoever wrote that answer was really on top of it.

Comment: According to RoguePlanetoid "I think the original concept for the movie the human mind was meant to be used as a single node on a complex neural network - so that humans added more processing power to the matrix system, which makes more sense than just using them for power and explained why keeping them in a persistant vegetative state wouldn't make sense, I think the movie would still work as the threat of too many minds leaving the system would remove capacity and processing from the Matrix"

Comment: Make them obese (via a tv and endless supply of twinkies) and reap their fat (complex carbon chains that can be oxidized for fuel) via liposuction. Many would happily consent that his symbiosis.

Answer (score 1):

**100 million people**, assuming US power consumption and perfect generators. half that for more realistic generators.  (Your mileage may vary.)

According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_power 
"A healthy well-fed laborer over the course of an 8-hour work shift can sustain an average output of about 75 watts."  If we assume they work seven days a week, 8 hour shifts, the average power ouput per capita (or should I say 'per captive', since this sounds like a horrible fate) would be 25 watts.  (And if you are reading this on a laptop or desktop PC, you're using more than that!)

How much power will this city's people use, on average?
based on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_electricity_consumption, this varies wildly.  In the US, the given average power consumption is 1843 watts (streetlights, factories making your food and stuff, everything.)

To me, the interesting thing is the ratio of power used to power that person could produce: 1843/25 is a factor of over 70!

Using these same numbers, plus a population estimate of 7.4 Billion people:

7.4e9 * (25 / 1843) = 100,379,815 people!

**Using everybody on the planet pedaling, assuming 100% generator efficiency, could support a city of about 100 million, at US current power consumption.  If the generators were 50% efficient, then only half that number, around 50 million.**

(People aren't very useful as large power sources, at least not very useful compared to first-world *per-capita* power consumption.)

Comment: Re (And if you are reading this on a laptop or desktop PC, you're using more than that!): Not necessarily.  Powertop shows my laptop usage at around 17 watts, when just doing web browsing &c.